# python find the closest point from two tables and print the pair names

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am new to python and looking at the solutions for my problem I only found the selection from one list. In my case have two tables

Table 1:

[image: table 1]

Table 2:

[image: table 2]

I would like to select the closest pair of points from two tables and as the output get the list of the pairs. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want one point from table1 and one point from table2 that are the closest.

You can try this..

```
import math

# finds the Euclidean distance
def getDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)

#finds the closest points from table1 and table2
def getClosestPoints(table1, table2):
    #pointA, pointB
    distance = None
    for x1,y1 in zip(table1['x'], table1['y']):
        for x2, y2 in zip(table2['x'], table2['y']):
            dis = getDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            #print (f"x1 = {x1}, y1 = {y1}, x2 = {x2}, y2 = {y2} | dis = {dis}")
            if distance == None or distance > dis:
                distance = dis
                pointA = (x1,y1)
                pointB = (x2,y2)
                #print(f"A={pointA}, B={pointB}, dis = {distance}")
            else:
                continue
    return pointA, pointB, distance
```

returns point 1, point 2 and the distance.

```
print(getClosestPoints(table1, table2))
```

Outputs: ((41.31175, 15.1337), (41.55, 14.96778), 0.2903317221730979)

which is ((x1, y1), (x2, y2), distance)